# Best way to publicize packages / paclets?

Tags: discussion

I recently wrote up a package for simple paclet construction which has made distributing my code so much simpler. The flip side of this, however, is that for a lot of what I make I have no good, unobtrusive way to let people know it exists, even when it's something that's free and probably reasonably useful for others.

This came to mind recently because I just knocked up a prototype GitHub hook-in to the service connection framework, and, since it's distributed as a paclet, it's essentially just a single line of code to install. Because of that (and because lots of people use GitHub) I thought that this was something that the MSE community might enjoy.

It comes to mind, therefore, that I'm not sure where's the best--i.e. least obtrusive but still noticeable--place to post about things like that. There's [PackageData.net](http://packagedata.net/), but I'm not sure how much people pay attention to it. As I discovered when knocking up a quick package index from what's there, much of the stuff is distributed on lab websites as notebooks -- which is to say not in immediately useful form. Then there's the [MSE GitHub](https://github.com/stackmma) but, once again, not sure who looks at it. It seems not to have been updated in ~4-5 years.

So how do other people put their stuff out there and in what format (e.g. paclet, application, etc.)?

( And just as a point of curiosity, who out there actively--i.e. in their free-time--develops packages for public consumption? )

Comment: I'm the author of the [Neurotica](https://github.com/noahbenson/Neurotica) package for neuroscience data in Mathematica. I may be the only person who actively uses it (not sure), but I've put a lot of effort into making it sleek and package-like in case someone else decides to. I believe [@Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) put it on PackageData for me awhile back. It includes an embedded Java library, so has a non-trivial installation, and I've never been sure quite how to bundle it for users. Only just discovered paclets when reading your question, though.

Comment: @user16054 there's a JLink extension to the PacletInfo if I remember correctly. That might simplify the installation some. If you want to turn it into a paclet (or rather give the directory the appropriate paclet format) I can write a tutorial for my paclet uploader and you can upload it like that, too. Might be worth making a Q/A on packages distributed as paclets, even, so people can find this stuff more easily.

Answer (score 2):

So I've been stewing over this and I'm still not sure what's best, but my current idea is to make a [landing page for my paclets](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-e4d1d43a-267f-4924-934a-2ba2321519a9/paclets/PacletServer/main.html)

And then provide access to them via a listing of tiles:

[image: paclet server landing page]

The nice thing about this is I can just pull the data out of the PacletSite.mz file I have to upload anyway.